# useSwr fetch with filter query params

Tags: next.js

I have a component which displays a list of sources. Users will be able to filter this list with search keywords.
I have a state called `searchKeyword` which holds the input value.
I need to make a request when user clicks on search.

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(`source-requests/favorite?keyword=${searchKeyword}`);

const submitSearch = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   mutate(source-requests/favorite?keyword=${searchKeyword});
};
```

This makes call on every keystroke. How do I prevent this.

Comment: Where is `submitSearch` being called from? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating searchKeyword on each keystroke, the useSWR key will be updated on every keystroke too - and thus it will make a fetch on each keystroke.

It's difficult to tell if this is the case without seeing the full example.

If searchKeyword is held in useState, you could do something like this, where searchKeyword is only updated on form submission:

```js
const [searchKeyword, setSearchKeyword] = useState(null)

const { data, error } = useSWR(
  searchKeyword
  ? `source-requests/favorite?keyword=${searchKeyword}`
  : null
);

const Form = () => {
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSearchKeyword(event.target.form.search.value)
        console.log(`Form submitted, ${searchKeyword}`);    
    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="" />
            <button type='submit'>Search</button>
        </form>
    );
    
}
```